# Flutter Pass parameter with Nested widget

Tags: flutter, class, architecture, nested, refactoring

I am new to flutter.

But i want to refactoring a code.

So i extract widget for separate looping widget.

But there is problem. When i do separate widget, i also have to pass parameter of parent widget.

So i add again and again and again. But i don’t think this is best way to pass parameter.

I know ChangeNotifierProvider but this like static variable, so it change another that use same state variable. So can’t use for my situation.

Can you recommend other methods for me?
At least if you comment keyword of recommend method i will deep dive into it.

ex)
Parent(value: value)
——Child(value: value)
———GrandChild(value: value)

Comment: Use a state management library like Riverpod, Provider or Bloc

Comment: Thanks to you(@lmtiaz Ayon), I realized that it was not a matter of method, but that I was designing the structure wrong and not grasping the concepts properly.